# Symfony2 - Where should I put files uploaded by users?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I am new with Symfony and I put images uploded by users under `/web/bundles/mybundle/images/` directory. But I feel it's not good practice. Because when I run command below to create symlinks to other files under `src` directory. All images uploaded by users were removed.

```
php app/console assets:install ./web --symlink
```

Where should I put images uploaded by users?

Comment: Personally i put them in /web/uploads/bundle/controller/action

Comment: Did you follow the [Symfony2 cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html) in order to manage the file upload? It should add the uploaded file in the best place.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My personal solution is to put them in the `/app/data/uploads` directory, and then either:

1. Create symlinks to the upload directory, or
2. Serve the uploads via a controller

Option 1 is probably your best bet for images and assets, as you want them served as quickly as possible.  However, for other content (PDFs, Docs, etc), option 2 might be your better bet, as you have more control over how you want the content served.

I prefer to keep my `/web` directory as clean as possible, and keep file uploads outside of public scope (allowing me to change my method of serving the files without needing to move them -- IE Moving from Option 1 above to Option 2), but if you want to store them in the web folder, you can follow the [Symfony Cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html) and store them in something like `/web/uploads`.

Comment: Thank you I will try first option