# Where is the best place to save some private User image on Symfony2?

Tags: image, symfony, save

My question is pretty simple: where can I save some user private images? what is the best practice for it?
I don't want that everybody can access on this file, so I exclude /web/images.

I take every advises!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Symfony2 - Where should I put files uploaded by users?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19458055/symfony2-where-should-i-put-files-uploaded-by-users)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard about it... A possible solution is to store it on your server (where you want) but not available via your web server (as you pointed, outside your web directory). Personally, I create a folder called `data` at the root directory of the project. Then, just create a controller which will serve your file.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Wouter J it's helped me.

If there is no best practice about save some users files, I think it's better to create another directory for storing this.

So I create web/../data and I stock the files there:

`data/user1/cover/cover.jpg
data/user1/profile/profile.jpg
data/user1/upload/pic_001.jpg
data/user2/cover/cover.jpg
...`

I obviously use a controller for manage the operations.